# How to get the Google Chrome INSPECT TOOL icon to apear

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I want to use Chrome to inspect HTML and view the HTML/CSS affecting an element on the page.

This video shows that in Dev Tools Mode you can click the Elements tab and click the Inspect icon (magnifying glass). But that menu is not there.

[image]

I'm using chrome:  Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: That's some really ancient video. The icon is now different and can be invoked via Ctrl-Shift-C or in the toolbar, which is on the top of devtools Elements panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is now different and can be invoked via `Ctrl-Shift-C` or in the toolbar, which is on the top of devtools Elements panel. 
(answer provided by commentor above)